# How to list available app commands in terminal

Tags: terminal, command

I'm using fluxbox and recently i wanted to start an application for video editing and i couldn't remember it's name. I usually run apps from terminal so I was wondering is there a way to list all (applications or) app specific commands like Xmonad's "run or raise" feature? 
This feature can be seen here at 1:14 : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyNkBLhIpQk&feature=related

Edit : I want to te able to type a command in terminal that will return the list of all applications installed (the list of all application commands available e.g. shotwell, gedit, gvim, vim, vi, firefox, chromium-browser etc.) basically i want to know which apps I can run (which apps i have)

Comment: Your question isn't clear: are you typing the application name in a [shell in a terminal](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con/4132#4132), or in Fluxbox?

Comment: Press `Tab` twice in your terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `bash(1)`, you can use the `compgen` builtin:

```
$ compgen -abc -A function
```

`-a` for aliases, `-b` for builtins, `-c` for commands and `-A function` for shell functions. You can choose which if these you want to exclude, as you'll get a rather large list (on my system I get 3206 commands).

The `compgen` command is meant for generating command line completion candidates, but can be used for this purpose too.

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial if we assume that "apps you can run" is synonymous with "executables in your path":

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=: read -ra _dirs_in_path <<< "$PATH"

for _dir in "${_dirs_in_path[@]}"; do
    for _file in "${_dir}"/*; do
        [[ -x ${_file} && -f ${_file} ]] && printf '%s\n' "${_file##*/}"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you type at least one letter, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you'll see a list of all the executable programs whose name begins with that letter. This is called [completion or autocomplete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete).

You can list all the executable programs with this shell snippet:

```
( IFS=':'; set -f;
  for dir in $PATH; do
    for x in $dir/*; do echo $x; done
  done )
```

This lists all the executable programs you have, which may be more general than what you intend by “all applications”. You'll also see a number of commands which are intended to be called by other commands, and are rarely invoked directly by users. A list of the applications that are intended to be invoked from a GUI is available through the `*.desktop` files under `/usr/share/applications`. The following command will display them (you'll find crumbs like `%u`, `%c` and so on, indicating what kinds of arguments the command typically expects; they are described in the [desktop file format specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables)).

```
grep -Proh '(?<=^Exec=).*' /usr/share/applications
```

You may get a better feel for what applications you have installed by listing the packages you have: `dpkg -l` under Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives; `rpm -ql` under Red Hat, Fedora, SuSE and derivaties; …

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but i solved it with the previous answer, whatsoever i don't question your solution but i don't have time to try it. Thanks once again.