# Are there foreign language Terminal command sets?

Tags: shell, command-line

I recently changed my MacBook's UI to show Hebrew, and at around the same time, I began using the Terminal more often. The combination of the two has lead me to wonder - are there Hebrew language commands, or any other non-english language command sets available for the terminal either on Unix, Linux, or Mac OS?

([This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24507/how-to-list-available-app-commands-in-terminal) leads me to wonder if an entirely separate shell implementation is required for something like that, if it's even possible.)

Are there foreign language Terminal command sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a cool idea, but I don't think it exists. Alternatively, you could write your own wrappers (in Hebrew in your case) either as executable code or as an alias in your `~/.bashrc`.

Something like:

```
alias [hebrew_for_add_a_user]='useradd'
```

I would personally opt for the alias implementation.